# Class constructor cannot be invoked without new when using tsyringe in react.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsyringe

I am using tsyringe for Dependency Injection in react.js app created using create-react-app. I have a singleton class which is used in other class called TestRepositoryImpl.

```
import { singleton } from "tsyringe";

@singleton()
class SingletonClass {
    //...
}

export default SingletonClass;
```

Repository Class

```
import { autoinjectable} from "tsyringe";
import TestRepository from "../domain/TestRepository";
import SingletonClass from "./SingletonClass";

@autoinjectable()
class TestRepositoryImpl implements TestRepository {

  constructor(singletonClass: SingletonClass){}

  test(){
      console.log("Test Function");
  }
}

export default TestRepositoryImpl;
```

When this class is called using container. I got the following error.
[Class constructor cannot be invoked without new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUXEc.png)

Here is my config files.
**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "tsyringe": "^4.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
}
```

I have tried replacing autoinjectable with singleton from TestRepositoryImpl class. Then it throws an [type info not known error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUemF.png).
I have also replaced tsyringe with inversify and it was not working.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the review, I have made the changes.

Comment: If you are using CRA, you will not be able to use tsyring without ejecting. I recommend trying `iti` + `iti-react` packages. I wrote them just for that